# Exporting table data without the schema?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've tried searching for this but so far I'm only finding results for "exporting the table schema without data," which is exactly the opposite of what I want to do. Is there a way to export data from a SQL table without having the script recreate the table?

Here's the problem I'm trying to solve if someone has a better solution: I have two databases, each on different servers; I'll call them the raw database and the analytics database. The raw database is the "real" database and collects records sent to its server, and stores them in a table using the transactional InnoDB engine. The analytics database is on an internal LAN, and is meant to mirror the raw database and will periodicly be updated so that it matches the raw database. It's separated like this because we have a program that will do some analysis and processing of the data, and we don't want to do it on the live server.

Because the analytics database is just a copy, it doesn't need to be transactional, and I'd like it to use the MyISAM engine for its table because I've found it to be much faster to import data into and query against. The problem is that when I export the table from the live raw database, the table schema gets exported too and the table engine is set to InnoDB, so when I run the script to import the data into the analytics database, it drops the MyISAM table and recreates it as an InnoDB table. I'd like to automate this process of exporting/importing data, but this problem of the generated sql script file changing the table engine from MyISAM to InnoDB is stopping me, and I don't know how to get around it. The only way I know is to write a program that has direct access to the live raw database, do a query, and update the analytics database with the results, but I'm looking for alternatives to this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this?

```
mysqldump --no-create-info ...
```

Comment: Alternatively, If you have access to UNIX tools, you could mysqldump with the table schema, and pipe it through sed: mysqldump myDB | sed 's/InnoDB/MyISAM/g' > dumpasMyISAM.txt

Comment: Perfect, thanks! For future reference, short-form for this option is `-t`, and there's a corresponding `--no-create-db` to not create databases (with short-form `-n`). There's also the `--where='...'` (short-form `-w '...'`) option if one wants to specify specific records to dump.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `no-create-info` option

```
mysqldump --no-create-info db [table]
```